# Swift 2.2 decrementing specific for loop in Swift 3

Tags: swift, for-loop, refactoring, operators, stride

I have the task to refactor an iOS app to Swift 3. However, there is a `for` loop, in C-style, that does more than just looping an array backwards (it's mandatory to be backwards).

This is a sample code. The principle is the same.

```
let array = ["hello", "world", nil, "foo", nil, "bar", "Peter Griffin"]
var threeLetterWords = 0
for var i = array.count-1; i >= 0 && array[i].characters.count == 3; --i, ++threeLetterWords { }
print("Found words: \(threeLetterWords)") // should say `Found words: 2`
```

I tried with `stride(from:through:by:)` but I can't increment `threeLetterWords` as it seems important to increment it in the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Any C-style for loop can be replace with a while loop.

Comment: Your code counts the number of 3-letter words at the end of the array.  It would return 0 for your test array.

Comment: I now fully understand why C-style for loops were removed.

Comment: @Alexander, you've got that right.  There is some really evil code out there abusing C-style for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't counting the number of 3-letter words in the array.  It is counting the number of 3-letter words at the end of the array.  It will return `0` for your sample input array.

When a C-style *for* loop is very complex, the final fallback solution is to translate it to a *while* loop.  Any C-style *for* loop can be mechanically converted into an equivalent *while* loop, which means you can do it even if you don't fully understand what it is doing.

This *for* loop:

```
for initialization; condition; increment {
    // body
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
initialization
while condition {
    // body
    increment
}
```

So, your code is equivalent to:

```
let array = ["hello", "world", nil, "foo", nil, "bar", "Peter Griffin"]
var threeLetterWords = 0

var i = array.count - 1
while i >= 0 && array[i]?.characters.count == 3 {
    i -= 1
    threeLetterWords += 1
}
print("Found words: \(threeLetterWords)") // says `Found words: 0`
```

---

Here is how to use a *for* loop and *guard* to do the equivalent of your code:

```
let array = ["hello", "world", nil, "foo", nil, "bar", "Peter Griffin"]
var num3LetterWords = 0

for word in array.reversed() {
    guard word?.characters.count == 3 else { break }
    num3LetterWords += 1
}

print(num3LetterWords)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//for var i = array.count-1; i >= 0 && array[i].characters.count == 3; --i, ++threeLetterWords { }

for i in stride(from: (array.count-1), through: 0, by: -1) {
    threeLetterWords += 1

    if (array[i]?.characters.count == 3) {
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your array indices reversed and add a where clause for the characters count:

```
let array = ["hello", "world", nil, "foo", nil, "bar", "Peter Griffin"]
var threeLetterWords = 0

for index in array.indices.reversed() where array[index]?.characters.count == 3 {
    threeLetterWords += 1
}

print("Found words: \(threeLetterWords)") // should say `Found words: 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody here is very unnecessarily complicating this.

```
let words = ["hello", "world", nil, "foo", nil, "bar", "Peter Griffin"]

var num3LetterWords = 0

for word in words.reversed() {
    if (word?.characters.count == 3) { num3LetterWords += 1 }
}

print(num3LetterWords)
```

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complex way of doing `print(words.count)`.

Comment: @vacawama hahaha I forgot to copy in my if statement, fixed.

Comment: You need to unwrap: `word?.characters.count == 3`.  This counts the 3 letter words, but it isn't equivalent to OP's original code which actually counts the number of 3-letter words at the end of the array.

Comment: @vacawama I'm aiming to reproduce the behaviour he "spirit" of the code, rather than "word" of the code, because I suspect OP just made a mistake in producing this shitty example

Comment: I believe the spirit of their question is how do I translate a complex C-style for loop into something equivalent in Swift 3, because their question admits that they have some complex example they didn't want to share and made up this example as a replacement.  Given that we don't know how complex their loop is, I figured I'd show them the *last fallback scenario* which is to convert it to a while loop, *especially* if you don't understand the original code.