# How to write this code in swift 3.0. using For loop

Tags: swift

How to write this code in swift 3.0. using For loop?

```
for (int index = 0; index < 100; index += (1 + index)) {        
    printf("%d\t",index);      
}
```

Comment: That code seems pointless.

It's going to yield strange results.

Swift no longer has the C-style `for (;;)` construct, so you'll have to build that with a while loop.
This smells like a homework assignment to me. Is it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42662061/1630618

Answer (score 1):

You increment is increasing. Since the C-style for loop isn't available, you might use code like this:

```
var index = 0
while index < 100 {
  print("\(index)", terminator: "\t")
  index += 1 + index
}
print("")
```

You could also write this code in functional style:

```
for f in sequence(first: 0,
                  next: {
                    $0 + $0 + 1
})
  .prefix(while: {$0 < last}) {
    print(f, terminator: "\t")
}
print("")
```

(The prefix function requires Swift 3.1)

Comment: Up voted for correct translation including use of print with terminator.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of `for` loop came from C, and counter to the design and spirit of the Swift language. That’s why it was eliminated in Swift 3 (you can find out more about its removal [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md)).

C-style for loops have three statements:

First, there’s the **initialization statement,** where you set up one or more variables. In this case, the initialization statement is:

```
int index = 0
```

which in Swift becomes

```
var index = 0
```

Then, there’s the **loop invariant,** which is a condition that must be true at the very start and end of each pass through the loop. In this case, the loop invariant is:

```
index < 100
```

The Swift code is pretty much the same as the C code.

And finally, there’s what I call the **change statement,** which makes a change to some condition in the loop, which needs to be evaluated to see if another pass needs to be made through the loop. In this case, it’s this statement:

```
index += 1 + index
```

Again, the Swift code is pretty much the same as the C code.

You should use a while loop, and the equivalent Swift code looks like this:

```
while index < 100 {
  print("\(index)\t")
  index += 1 + index
}
```

The `index += 1 + index` code, while valid, is unusual. Are you sure you wanted that, or did you want the more common `index += 1`?

Comment: Good, clear, step-by-step answer. One minor point though. The C `printf()` function does not terminate the line, where the Swift `print()` function does by default. In my answer, I provide the optional terminator parameter, which replaces the normal line break with a tab. Your code would show each step in the loop on a new line, which would be different than the C code provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a for loop, you could use a sequence but that would be more verbose and cumbersome than a while loop:

```
for index in  sequence(first:0, next:{ let index = $0 + $0 + 1; return index < 100 ? index : nil})
{
  print("\(index)")
}
```

You could also generalize this to any type and increments using a generic function:

```
func cFor<T>(_ start:T, _ condition:@escaping (T)->Bool, _ increment:@escaping (inout T)->()) -> UnfoldSequence<T, (T?, Bool)>
{
   return sequence(first:start, next:{ var next = $0; increment(&next); return condition(next) ? next : nil })
}

for index in cFor(0,{$0<100},{$0 += $0 + 1})
{
  print("\(index)")
}
```