# how to use modifying for-loop in Swift 3.2?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, swift3.2

I have a converted for-loop in `Swift 3.2` that looks similar to this:

```
for var i in 0..<char.characters.count {
    if(self.characters.count > len  && ((currentIndex + length2323) < length))
    {
      i = i - 1
    }
}
```

But, It doesn't work properly. I want to continue loop when set value for `i` is `i = i - 1` but this code getting out of loop

And my previous `Swift 2` code is :

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < char.characters.count ; i += 1) {
     if(self.characters.count > len  && ((currentIndex + length2323) < length))
     {
        i = i - 1
     }
}
```

Comment: You can always convert a C-style for loop to a while loop like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662061/1630618)

Comment: Btw, can you explain what `if` inside loop does?

Comment: please try my code bellow, it would be great if you post all your code with cntext and what problem it should solve...

Comment: Is `i` used for something that's not included in this code? In the code you've included no variables are modified and `i` is only available inside the loop body (and isn't read or passed anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 syntax**

```
import UIKit
var char = "char"
var len = 9
var currentIndex = 1
var length2323 = 2323
var length = 17
for var i in 0..<char.count {
if (self.count > len)  && ((currentIndex + length2323) < length) {
    i = i - 1
}
```

}

**Swift 3.2 syntax**

```
import UIKit
var char = "char"
var len = 9
var currentIndex = 1
var length2323 = 2323
var length = 17
for var i in 0..<char.characters.count {
if (self.characters.count > len)  && ((currentIndex + length2323) < length) {
    i = i - 1
}
```

}

Comment: Why is `i` both the characters and the number inside the loop body? Also, if you define/shadow `i` inside the loop body like that it will be a new value that starts at `0` for each iteration. I don't think that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: In your for loop you just changed `for var i in 0..<characters.count` to `for var i in 0...char.characters.count` So its work for me?

Comment: @New-Learner what does you if statement should do? Probably problem in "self". What self object is ?

Comment: @swift2geek self contain string like ("Peri Peri Sauce Chinese Menu4")

Comment: @New-Learner ok, than self should be in if statement, i've made some changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164261/discussion-between-swift2geek-and-new-learner).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (index, item) in char.enumerated()
{
      //your loop
}
```